# Validate Postgres jsonpath predicate with python

Tags: python, postgresql, jsonb, predicate, jsonpath

I'am using Postgresql jsonpath predicate https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html in a python program with SQLAlchemy ORM. The test being run is the one matching jsonb @@ jsonpath → boolean.

The jsonpath example in the Postgresql documentation above is :

```
'{"a":[1,2,3,4,5]}'::jsonb @@ '$.a[*] > 2' → t
```

If I try to validate the jsonpath predicate '$.a[*] > 2' using python jsonpath-ng with :

```
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse
jsonpath_expr = parse('$.a[*] > 2')
```

I get an exception stating:

```
Parse error at 1:7 near token > (FILTER_OP)
```

If I use a valid jsonpath predicate as per jsonpath-ng with Postgresql JSONB @@ operator , I get a Postgresql exception.

My questions are:

- is the jsonpath precidate of Postgresql incompatible with the standard jsonpath ?
- how to make both jsonpath predicate comptatible between Postgresql JSONB and the standard ?

For my program, the jsonpath predicate may be entered from command line which requires a validation before being run. Otherwise, I get a Postgresql generic error which I want to deal with before.

Comment: Postgres follows the rule of SQL/JSON path. I don't know if there is a formal specification of JSONPath in general (outside of SQL/JSON). But https://jsonpath.com/ as well as https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/ reject `$.a[*] > 2` as a valid JSON path

Comment: This is unfortunate to have 2 incompatible jsonpath standards . That makes somehow none of them standard as a matter of fact.

Comment: Well, as there is a standard as part of the SQL standard, the only sensible way for Postgres is to comply with that.

Comment: Thx a lot for your response. What would be the proper way to validate the SQL/JSON using Python ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no general standard of JSONPath. Popular modules in JS, Python and PHP are based on [the document](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) that does not exhaust the subject in the slightest and can be treated as a draft. Currently, the standardization of this issue [is in progress](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base/08/).

> What would be the proper way to validate the SQL/JSON using Python?

Execute a query trying to cast a value to `jsonpath`, e.g.:

```py
def validate_jsonpath_value(jsonpath_value):
    with psycopg2.connect(dsn) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                cursor.execute('select %s::jsonpath', [jsonpath_value])
            except psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError as e:
                print(e)
                return False
    return True
```

Postgres jsonpath parser gives accurate information about possible syntactic errors.